# Unable to get index, NaN was returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am trying to fetch a tile's neighbour in a hexagonal grid.
Both grids and tiles are React components, and I have a method handy in my Grid component to find all of a tile's neighbours

The method works fine for neighbours within the index, and I set up a modulus to wrap around to the other side of the grid if a tile was to get out of bounds. Those indexes return NaN.

```
  /**
   * Returns all neighbouring tiles of this tile
   */
  getTileNeighbours(tile) {
    // Checks all arrays in the two-dimensional grid if this tile exists
    for (let i in this.state.grid) {
      let array = this.state.grid[i]

      for (let j in array) {
        console.log("Looking...")
        let item = array[j]

        if (item.state.name === tile.state.name) {
          console.log("Found you!")
          // Gets the position of the tile
          let j = array.indexOf(tile)
          //console.log(`Tile was found at position [${i}, ${j}]. Returning neighbours.`)

          let neighbours = []
          // All possible permutations of neighbours
          let positions = [
            {i:0,j:-2}, {i:1,j:-1}, {i:1,j:1}, {i:0,j:2}, {i:-1,j:1}, {i:-1,j:-1}
          ]

          // If neighbouring indexes are out of bounds, wraps around to the other edge of the arrays
          for (let k in positions) {
            let position = positions[k]

            let xIndex = (i + position.i) % this.state.grid.length
            let yIndex = (j + position.j) % array.length
            console.log(`Resolving '(${i} + ${position.i}) % ${this.state.grid.length}': ${(i + position.i) % this.state.grid.length}`)
            console.log(`Actual indexes used: 'this.state.grid[${xIndex}][${yIndex}]'`)

            let match = this.state.grid[xIndex][yIndex]

            if (match) neighbours.push(match)
          }
          return neighbours
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Here's a capture of my JavaScript console in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBGxR.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I am getting `Resolving '(0 + -1) % 12': -1
Actual indexes used: 'this.state.grid[-1][1]'` in my console. Could you please add a bit more background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong, it all came down to the variable types not all being numbers. i, j and k are all strings (since they are used in a `for (x in y)` context), at k = 5, we end up with `i + position.i` being equal to `0-1` as a string, which cannot be used with a modulus. By forcing `i` and `j` to be numbers, we no longer encounter our NaN.
Similarly, using the modulus to wrap around was a bad idea altogether.
It has been replaced with a ternary to add the length of the array when the resulting index was negative
Two lines were all I needed to change, here they are

```
let xIndex = Number(i) + position.i < 0 ? Number(i) + position.i + this.state.grid.length : Number(i) + position.i
let yIndex = Number(j) + position.j < 0 ? Number(j) + position.j + array.length : Number(j) + position.j
```

This was all due to a gross lack of attention on my end, I should have troubleshooted better.